# Parsing a tree from a nested list in Java

Tags: java, parsing, tree, nested-lists

I have to create a tree from a nested list of integers in Java, like this:

((3,8,(7,(3,0,7),(8,8,2))),
     (4,(7,9,8),8),
     (((3,6,4),2,6),((9,2,9),4,7,(6,4,5) ),4,(6,4,5))
    )

would be parsed to this tree: https://gyazo.com/189e2a4936913f9025b501be86aabc35/

I just can't seem to visualize how the nested list becomes the tree...

NOTE, a blank space means the tree value is empty

Comment: *I just can't seem to visualize how the nested list becomes the tree...* - This seems to be homework. Did you try asking your teacher?

Comment: I don't think you are ready to ask a question here yet, because you haven't started coding.  You're going to need to write a parser of some sort to consume the input string.  Then, you'll have to generate a tree.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a node is either a leaf with a number, or a list of nodes:

```
public abstract class Node {
}

public class NumberNode extends Node {
    private final int number;

    public NumberNode(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(number);
    }
}

public class ListNode extends Node {
    private final List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListNode(Collection<Node> nodes) {
        list.addAll(nodes);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.append('(');
        boolean first = true;
        for (Node node: list) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                buf.append(',');
            }
            buf.append(node);
        }
        buf.append(')');
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

You may want to use a scanner to tokenize your input:

```
public class Scanner {
    private final Reader in;
    private int c;
    private Token token;
    private int number;

    public static enum Token {LPAR,RPAR,NUMBER,COMMA,EOF};

    public Scanner(Reader in) throws IOException {
        this.in = in;
        c = in.read();
    }

    public Token getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public Token nextToken() throws IOException {
        while (c == ' ') {
            c = in.read();
        }
        if (c < 0) {
            return token = Token.EOF;
        }
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            number = c - '0';
            c = in.read();
            while (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                number = 10*number + (c-'0');
                c = in.read();
            }
            return token = Token.NUMBER;
        }
        switch (c) {
            case '(':
                c = in.read();
                return token = Token.LPAR;
            case ')':
                c = in.read();
                return token = Token.RPAR;
            case ',':
                c = in.read();
                return token = Token.COMMA;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown character " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then write a parser:

```
public static Node parse(Reader in) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
    scanner.nextToken();
    return parse(scanner);
}

private static Node parse(Scanner scanner) throws IOException {
    switch (scanner.getToken()) {
        case NUMBER:
            int value = scanner.getNumber();
            scanner.nextToken();
            return new NumberNode(value);
        case LPAR:
            scanner.nextToken();
            List<Node> nodes = parseList(scanner);
            if (scanner.getToken() != Token.RPAR) {
                throw new RuntimeException(") expected");
            }
            scanner.nextToken();
            return new ListNode(nodes);
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Number or ( expected");
    }
}

private static List<Node> parseList(Scanner scanner) throws IOException {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    if (scanner.getToken() != Token.RPAR) {
        nodes.add(parse(scanner));
        while (scanner.getToken() == Token.COMMA) {
            scanner.nextToken();
            nodes.add(parse(scanner));
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

To parse your example:

```
        String s = "((3,8,(7,(3,0,7),(8,8,2))), (4,(7,9,8),8), (((3,6,4),2,6),((9,2,9),4,7,(6,4,5) ),4,(6,4,5)) )";
        System.out.println(s);
        Node node = parse(new StringReader(s));
        System.out.println(node);
```

Output:

```
((3,8,(7,(3,0,7),(8,8,2))), (4,(7,9,8),8), (((3,6,4),2,6),((9,2,9),4,7,(6,4,5) ),4,(6,4,5)) )
((3,8,(7,(3,0,7),(8,8,2))),(4,(7,9,8),8),(((3,6,4),2,6),((9,2,9),4,7,(6,4,5)),4,(6,4,5)))
```